# Matplotlib points do not show up in png figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to save a figure as a png image, and am having weird behavior:

```
import numpy as np                                                                            
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                               
import os                                                                                     

if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                    
    a = np.random.random(100)                                                                 
    b = np.random.random(100)                                                                 
    plt.plot(a, 'k')                                                                          
    #the following line does not show up properly                                             
    plt.plot(b, 'r.')                                                                         
    #the following line will show up properly                                                 
    #plt.plot(b, 'r', alpha = 0.5)                                                            
    plt.savefig('test.png', dpi = 300)                                                        
    os.system('open test.png')
```

when using the "red point" setting `r.`, the data points do not show up.  Replacing this with `r`, they do show up.  Saving as `pdf` instead of `png`, and they show up in all cases.  Setting `plt.show()` instead of `plt.savefig(...)`, and they show up, but when saving from the gui, they vanish again.

Why are they not showing up in the .png setting?

PS-I'm using Python 2.7 with the Agg renderer on OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Not reproducible on Ubuntu, python 2.7, matplotlib 1.4.2. Have you tried with a different backend? (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31706568/4481445.)